# Smart contract return hexbytes object instead of an int

Tags: python, hex, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm working on a smart contract that is suppose to return 1 when I call it with a python script using web3.py, but  instead of having a 1 in my python scirpt I receive an hexbytes object. I suppose I need to decode it using the ABI and web3.py but I don't know how?

I have a function like this in solidity:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

contract test {
    function test(int a) public returns (int) {
            if(a > 0){
                return 1;
            }
        }
}
```

When I called it with my python script:

```
import json

import web3
from web3 import Web3

#To connect to ganache blockchain:
ganache_url = "http://127.0.0.1:7545"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ganache_url))

#this script will be the account number 1 on ganache blockchain:
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[1]

#smart contract: abi, address and bytecode
abi = json.loads('....')
address = web3.toChecksumAddress("0x4A4AaA64857aa08a709A3470A016a516d3da40bf")
bytecode = "..."

#refering to the deploy coontract
contract = web3.eth.contract(address = address, abi = abi, bytecode = bytecode)

con = contract.functions.test(52).transact()
print(con.hex())
```

I have result like this:

```
<class 'hexbytes.main.HexBytes'>
0x3791e76f3c1244722e60f72ac062765fca0c00c25ac8d5fcb22c5a9637c3706d
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You have a logic error on line 85. It should say `a == b`, not `a != b`. In all seriousness, what library are you using? What's your code? What's your input? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What? I don't know what you mean since I don't have these kind of condition in my code?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: That's much better. I've voted to reopen, let's see if it gets reopened. In the meantime, consult the documentation: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html

Comment: It says [here](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction.transact) that `transact` "Returns the transaction hash.", like in your case. Maybe you should've used `call`, as shown in the above link